# E: Unable to acquire the dpkg frontend lock (/var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend), are you root? (trying to update ubuntu)

Tags: apt, nvidia, dpkg, dependencies

```
root@chels-5f46dc6b67-7tct5:/data/home/AlphaPose# sudo apt install update-manager-core
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 cuda-drivers : Depends: nvidia-418 (>= 418.126.02) but it is not going to be installed
 libcuda1-418 : Depends: nvidia-418 but it is not going to be installed
 nvidia-418-dev : Depends: nvidia-418 (>= 418.126.02) but it is not going to be installed
 nvidia-opencl-icd-418 : Depends: nvidia-418 but it is not going to be installed
 update-manager-core : Depends: python3-update-manager (= 1:18.04.11.13) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: python3-distro-info but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: ubuntu-release-upgrader-core (>= 1:18.04.9) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
root@chels-5f46dc6b67-7tct5:/data/home/AlphaPose# apt --fix-broken install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  nvidia-418
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  nvidia-418
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 113 not upgraded.
8 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 97.9 MB of archives.
After this operation, 410 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Get:1 http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu1404/x86_64  nvidia-418 418.126.02-0ubuntu1 [97.9 MB]
Fetched 97.9 MB in 1s (67.1 MB/s)     
debconf: unable to initialize frontend: Dialog
debconf: (No usable dialog-like program is installed, so the dialog based frontend cannot be used. at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/FrontEnd/Dialog.pm line 76, <> line 1.)
debconf: falling back to frontend: Readline
(Reading database ... 128611 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../nvidia-418_418.126.02-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking nvidia-418 (418.126.02-0ubuntu1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/nvidia-418_418.126.02-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLX_indirect.so.0', which is also in package libglx-mesa0:amd64 20.0.8-0ubuntu1~18.04.1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/nvidia-418_418.126.02-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

How should I fix this? Can't install the update manager.

Comment: Can you please update your question to show only the problems you are still having, as you said in the comments on @user535733's answer that some where fixed?

Answer (score 1):

Read your input and your output carefully:

```
luqman@chels-5f46dc6b67-7tct5:~/AlphaPose$ apt --fix-broken install
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to acquire the dpkg frontend lock (/var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend), are you root?
```

No, you are not root. Looks like you forgot to use `sudo` on that command.

Comment: I see, but am now having a new problem after going to root

Comment: Of course you are. This is a lesson that your output is not meaningless babble. Your output includes important information that you can use to diagnose and fix the problem. Your lack-of-sudo was *specifically* hinted at in the output ("*permission denied*" and "*are you root?*") Your output seems to clearly describe multiple version conflicts. You installed something that conflicts with cuda, nvidia, and update manager. Search your memory for what you recently installed, and then uninstall it.